# Relationship between topics and speech acts/dialogue acts in a sentence

Tags: dialogue

I am still ambiguous about the relationship between topics and speech acts/dialogue acts in a sentence.

Are the topics selected as conditional on speech acts/dialogue acts (or vice versa) in a sentence? Or the both of topics and speech acts/dialogue acts occur simultaneously?

Comment: Hello RuizheLi.  I don't understand your question.  Could you give an example or explain a little more?

Comment: Good Question for [linguistics.se] -- proposing migration.

Comment: The Q belongs on [linguistics.se]

Comment: @Kris Yes; broader than English. And the terms need defining.

Comment: @Kris  you are right. I think my question is more suitable for Linguistics. Many thanks.